# Dict type python in return of arrays consults on MongoDB

Tags: python, json, mongodb

I use python for connect a mongodb database and the return of the consult is a dict type, but the document have arrays and dict python transform this arrays in a single string. I want navegate on this arrays, because I need get 'expanded_url' value.

Example of piece of document `{u'user_mentions': [], u'symbols': [], u'trends': [], u'hashtags': [], u'urls': [{u'url': u'http://t.co/JPYXHHsnj0', u'indices': [47, 69], u'expanded_url': u'http://4sq.com/1BQeRDp', u'display_url': u'4sq.com/1BQeRDp'}]}`

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What do you mean by `dict python transform this arrays in a single string`? Have you tried reading the contents of the dictionary like so: `document['urls'][0]['expanded_url']`?

Comment: A guess: `[url['expanded_url'] for doc in docs for url in doc['urls']]`